# Disable page scrolling when react-loading-overlay is active

Tags: reactjs

I am currently using [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loading-overlay) to show an overlay loader. I want however to remove the scrolling from the page when the loader is active while the loader stays in the center.

[Here is what I have so far](https://codesandbox.io/s/loadingoverlay-example-1lw55):

```
import LoadingOverlay from "react-loading-overlay";
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsloading] = useState(false);

  const handleLoading = () => {
    setIsloading(true);
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <LoadingOverlay active={isLoading} spinner text={"Loading"}>
        <div style={{ height: 1000, backgroundColor: "#a3ffd3" }}>
          You should see me when loading
        </div>
        <button onClick={handleLoading}>You can't see me when loading</button>
      </LoadingOverlay>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've tried `document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"` but it doesn't work as intended since the loader isn't centered but stays in the last scroll position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this:

```js
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (isLoading) {
      document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
      document.body.style.height = "100%";
    }
    if (!isLoading) {
      document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
      document.body.style.height = "auto";
    }
  }, [isLoading]);
```

Comment: The loader is still not in the center of the page

Comment: Adding the following fixed the center issue `._loading_overlay_overlay {
  position: fixed;
}`

Comment: @AnisBenna your question was to disable page scrolling when react-loading-overlay is active, not to provide a pixel perfect solution. You're welcome by the way. If this answers your initial question, please validate it so other people can benefit from the solution too.

Comment: My response was blank, my bad. I was going to validate after testing right away but I forgot. Great solution though, thank you. Perhaps you could explain the benefit of `useLayoutEffect` instead of `useEffect` in this particular case.

Comment: useLayoutEffect works the same than useEffect but is optimized to deal with layout changes. Basically, it runs while the component renders, and useEffect runs once the component has rendered. Here is a great article about it: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/useeffect-vs-uselayouteffect